# My HttpPost don't send data. What is wrong?

Tags: android

I'm making a new HttpPost app, but it doesn't send data to webpage post.php.

What am I making wrong?
What is wrong in my code?

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.pixelayer.httppost.httppost;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.opengl.Visibility;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private EditText value;
private Button btn;
private ProgressBar pb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    value=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    pb=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(value.getText().toString().length()<1){

        // out of range
        Toast.makeText(this, "please enter something", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
       pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        new MyAsyncTask().execute(value.getText().toString());
    }


}

private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{

    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        postData(params[0]);
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
        pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com/post.php");

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "3"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "test"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("site", "test"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

**ActivityMain.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"   android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Enter Something Below:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint=""
    >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="Submit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

This line is most likely throwing an exception, and you are ignoring all of your exceptions. Try logging them via adb like so:

```
    try {
       //...
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.d("MYAPP", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("MYAPP", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
```

Comment: I changed my code with your code above, but it is don't sending data to my webpage. What is wrong in my code ? Please, let me know.

Comment: You need to view the log message - it will tell you exactly what's wrong. Your code is correct but there are a lot of external variables as to why it's not working, and I cannot possibly tell you the answer.